# Probability of rolling 1 and 2 when rolling an unfair die 8 times

Tags: probability, self-study

If you roll a die 8 times, what is the probabiliy of getting both 1 and 2.

$P(1) = .3$

$ P(2) = .1$

$P(3) = .15$

$ P(4) = .15$

$P(5) = .15$

$P(6) = .15$

Comment: Sometimes it helps to think up ways of partitioning the set of all outcomes into disjoint sets. Maybe the outcomes where the 2 comes before the 1 and vice versa?

Answer (score 5):

I guess the easiest way to solve this is: 1-P(no 1)-P(no 2)+P(no 1 or 2) = $1-0.7^8-0.9^8+0.6^8$

We have to add +P(no 1 or 2) because otherwise we would be subtracting it twice. Ie. P(no 1) includes the case where we don't roll 1 or 2 and so does the P(no 2).

Another way would be to use Markov chain with states S={no 1 or 2, only 1, only 2, 1 and 2}. Corresponding transition matrix is:

$
D = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
0.6 & 0.3 & 0.1 & 0 \\
0 & 0.9 & 0 & 0.1 \\
0 & 0 & 0.7 & 0.3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] 
$

Then calculate $D^8$ etc.

Comment: +1 Interestingly, when you calculate the $(1,4)$ entry in $D^8$ by diagonalizing it, the resulting formula is *identical* to the one produced by the "easiest way": the eigenvalues are $1$, $0.7$, $0.9$, and $0.6$ and the signs $1,-1,-1,1$ come from the last row (or column) in the inverse of the transition matrix (matrix of eigenvectors).

Answer (score 0):

The probability of exactly a 1 once and a 2 once is 0.3(0.1)(0.6$^6$)=0.03(0.046656)=0.00139968 for each possible position of a 1 and a 2 to occur.  So we multiply 0.03 by that number.  The possiblilities are

```
(1) 12NNNNNN (2) 21NNNNNN (3) 1N2NNNNN (4) 2N1NNNNN
(5) 1NN2NNNN (6) 2NN1NNNN (7) 1NNN2NNN (8) 2NNN1NNN
(9) 1NNNN2NN (10)2NNNN1NN (11)1NNNNN2N (12)2NNNNN1N
(13)1NNNNNN2 (14)2NNNNNN1 (15)N12NNNNN (16)N21NNNNN
(17)N1N2NNNN (18)N2N1NNNN (19)N1NN2NNN (20)N2NN1NNN
(21)N1NNN2NN (22)N2NNN1NN (23)N1NNNN2N (24)N2NNNN1N
(25)N1NNNNN2 (26)N2NNNNN1 (27)NN12NNNN (28)NN21NNNN 
(29)NN1N2NNN (30)NN2N1NNN (31)NN1NN2NN (32)NN2NN1NN 
(33)NN1NNN2N (34)NN2NNN1N (35)NN1NNNN2 (36)NN2NNNN1 
(37)NNN12NNN (38)NNN21NNN (39)NNN1N2NN (40)NNN2N1NN 
(41)NNN1NN2N (42)NNN2NN1N (43)NNN1NNN2 (44)NNN2NNN1 
(45)NNNN12NN (46)NNNN21NN (47)NNNN1N2N (48)NNNN2N1N 
(49)NNNN1NN2 (50)NNNN2NN1 (51)NNNNN12N (52)NNNNN21N 
(53)NNNNN1N2 (54)NNNNN2N1 (55)NNNNNN12 (56)NNNNNN21
```

So the probability of exactly one 1 and one 2 is 56(0.00139968)=0.07838208 In addition to this we would add probability of two 1s and one two, one 1 and two 2s, two 1s and two 2s etc.

Comment: The probability of rolling a 1 once and a 2 once is $\binom{8}{2} 0.3 \cdot 0.1 \cdot 0.6^6$, but the question asks for the probability that you get at least one 1 and at least one 2.

Comment: @NeilG I chose to list the specific terms to get one 1 snd one 2 and pointed out how to get the other terms.  So I was aware of the question and pointed out how to get it without doing all the work for the OP. One can do the combinatorics but sometimes for beginners it helps to show how those results come about.

Comment: Illustrations like this indeed can be good, Michael, but basing this one on the problem as stated produces so much detail that insight may be hard to come by. Producing a similar illustration for a *simplified version* of the problem (such as four throws) and *formatting it* neatly (as a table or graphic) would better communicate your idea.

Comment: @whuber Yes I guess I could agree with that.  I tried to put it in a column form but the editor wouldn't allow it and unlike you I do not go to extraordinary efforts to create beautiful pictures.

Comment: (1) Removing the spaces between 1,2,N helps. (2) Beautiful pictures no longer take much effort or time; they only need facility with appropriate software. One thing about this site that initially impressed me was how *easily* people were able to offer great illustrations using `R`, typically needing just an extra (short) line of code. (To get the resulting image into a reply requires two short dialogs: one to save it on disk and another to load that onto the Web.) So, in practice, "extraordinary effort" often amounts just to an extra minute of work.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for doing that for me Bill.  Maybe I should have said "extra effort".  I appreciate the nice answers that you and many others have given on the site.  Your unit roots response was one great example of that.  I spend way too much time on this site.  That is how I got my reputation points up so fast (maybe with the help of a lot of good answers).  But I guess I don't want to go to the extra effort myself and I don't expect the moderators and other members to do it for me either (even though you often do).  I think people appreciate what I write anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about generating functions, you can do it as follows:

Let $a=0.3, b= 0.1, c=1-a-b$, then the answer is:
\begin{align}
\int_0^r\int_0^s\left.\frac{d^2(ax + by + c)^8}{dxdy}dxdy\right|_{r=s=1}
\end{align}

But, really, for this problem Seth's suggestion is best.  Try to break it into different cases whose probability you can easily calculate.  (You can do it with three terms.)

Answer (score 0):

=1- P(you don't roll a 1 or 2)

Comment: In this case is it much easier to compute P(you don't roll a 1 or 2)?  If so shouldn't you show why?

Comment: Maybe you want `1-P(not (1 and 2))`